# Grok patterns format in logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

Mostly my patterns working but after `Framework Error in :]` part does not see in the logs.

How can print rest of it on logs.
I tried at the last in patterns, but still does not work 
`%{GREEDYDATA:restofthem}`

My grok Pattern:

```
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:ServerTimestamp}\|%{WORD:Log4netHostname}\|%{DATA:ProjectName}\|%{DATA:TestName}\|%{DATA:UserName}\|%{DATA:ClientIP}\|%{DATA:ClientMachineName}\|%{LOGLEVEL:LogLevel}\|%{DATA:method}\|%{DATA:message}\|%{GREEDYDATA:Exception}|%{GREEDYDATA:Exception}\]%{GREEDYDATA:restofthem}
```

My Log:

```
[2018-06-05 13:26:57,641|host1|Appname|TTA|KKM|112.310.104.722|Host23|ERROR|Logger.Log4Net|LogError|Framework Error in :]
WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 5 seconds
 at DefaultWait`1.ThrowTimeoutException(String exceptionMessage, Exception lastException)
 at DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is, there is a new line after `:]` and You need to match `\n` character in order to parse it.
There are various different ways to do it, you can match a new line using `\n` character like this,

```
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:ServerTimestamp}\|%{WORD:Log4netHostname}\|%{DATA:ProjectName}\|%{DATA:TestName}\|%{DATA:UserName}\|%{DATA:ClientIP}\|%{DATA:ClientMachineName}\|%{LOGLEVEL:LogLevel}\|%{DATA:method}\|%{DATA:message}\|%{GREEDYDATA:Exception}\n%{GREEDYDATA:2ndLine}\n%{GREEDYDATA:3rdLine}\n%{GREEDYDATA:4thLine}
```

which will produce,

```
  ......

  "Exception": [
    [
      "Framework Error in :]"
    ]
  ],
  "2ndLine": [
    [
      "WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 5 seconds"
    ]
  ],
  "3rdLine": [
    [
      " at DefaultWait`1.ThrowTimeoutException(String exceptionMessage, Exception lastException)"
    ]
  ],
  "4thLine": [
    [
      " at DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)"
    ]
  ]
```

**OR,**

use `?m` to match all lines after the first line in one block like this,

```
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:ServerTimestamp}\|%{WORD:Log4netHostname}\|%{DATA:ProjectName}\|%{DATA:TestName}\|%{DATA:UserName}\|%{DATA:ClientIP}\|%{DATA:ClientMachineName}\|%{LOGLEVEL:LogLevel}\|%{DATA:method}\|%{DATA:message}\|%{GREEDYDATA:Exception}(?m)%{GREEDYDATA:everythingelse}
```

**Output,**

```
  .....
  ],
  "Exception": [
    [
      "Framework Error in :]"
    ]
  ],
  "everythingelse": [
    [
      "\nWebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 5 seconds\n at DefaultWait`1.ThrowTimeoutException(String exceptionMessage, Exception lastException)\n at DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)"
    ]
  ]
}
```